# Not able to publish app on gh-pages with angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-cli-ghpages

[image]I am trying to publish my app on gh-pages which is built on angular 7 followed couple of articles but didn't solve my issues
I tried steps below:

1. npm i -g angular-cli-ghpages
2. ng build --prod --base-href “https://username.github.io/repository_name/”
3. ngh

looked into github issue and followed steps but didn't help either

https://github.com/angular-schule/angular-cli-ghpages/issues/37

`ngh --dir dist/[PROJECTNAME]`
I typed above command it is running without any console error but my gh-pages shows only readme file at hosted url

Comment: Can you give github repo URL?

Comment: https://hir06.github.io/portfolio/ : gh-pages URL and repo url : https://github.com/hir06/portfolio

Comment: I am not able to find dist folder there

Comment: I haven't pushed it in master branch

Comment: As per my knowledge if you want to pulish your repo , just push your dist folder with docs name and point it into docs folder in the githiub repo settings

Comment: It's master branch are you saying I'll have to push it to gh-pages branch can you send me any link of the documentation regarding what you are saying

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186909/discussion-between-pardeep-jain-and-hiral).

Comment: https://theinfogrid.com/tech/developers/angular/deploying-angular-apps-github-pages/

Comment: Tried the same it again leads to readme file instead of actual content which it should serve

Comment: Bro, check now https://hir06.github.io/portfolio

Comment: Yup It's working now with docs folder push

Answer (score 1):

You can publish your angular application just pushing bundle (Dist folder with name of **docs**) on github.

and after that point build in the github repo settings to docs folder.

For more details refer -

- https://theinfogrid.com/tech/developers/angular/deploying-angular-apps-github-pages/